# Is it possible to COMPLETELY delete a Book from my purchased books?

Tags: books, itunes-store

Yesterday, I saw that my brother has downloaded an "hentai" on my Mac (shame on me, I didn't lock it !) I deleted it, but it stays on my purchased books, and I don't want it !

Is it possible to totally remove a book from my account's purchased history?

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but you should be able to open iTunes on a computer and sign in to your account. There is a "report problem" link next to all purchases and iBooks show up there for me. Have you asked Apple if you can remove that purchase from your history?

Answer (score 29):

This has since moved from iTunes to within the iBooks app, but the procedure is exactly the same:

1. Open iBooks
2. Click iBooks Store in top-left corner
3. Click Purchased
4. Click the x in the top-left corner of the book you want to hide

And to unhide:

1. Open iBooks
2. Click iBooks Store in top-left corner
3. Click Account
4. Click Manage next to Hidden Purchases
5. Click Unhide below book in question

Comment: Are you referring to the OS X apps or iOS apps? This doesn't seem to quite match how the iOS apps work.

Comment: This answer refers to the OS X / macOS iBooks app.

Answer (score 8):

If this was bought through the iBooks store, then things will stay in your purchase history for as long as they are available to download. You can try to contact Apple and explain that it was your brother that made the purchase on your account and you want it removed. Also, have your brother pay you back too.

If this was just a web download then if you delete the file from your Mac and synced devices it will be gone and bother you no more.

Comment: up-voted as the only one that actually answers the question.  "Delete" and "hide" are two different things.  And deleting it from iBooks is not deleting it from the purchased history.

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me using iBooks on the Mac.

Go to the iBooks store. Top left.

Scroll all the way down and select "purchased"

[image]

From here you should see the books. Hover over and click the X in the left side. Works in Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

so the answer is, No. it will be in the cloud permanently.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I found the answer on a French Forum. There is it :

Connect to the Store via iTunes for Mac (I think it works the same on windows but I didn't test)
Choose "Books" on the up "headband" (I don't know the English word, please correct :) )
Click on purchase on the right column
When you mouse over the book you want to delete, a X will appear. Click on it and your book will be hidden. It will be possible to download it again (for free I think, but again I didn't try) but it won't appear anymore in any of your device.

Et voilà ! I don't have this book on my iBook library any longer!

Answer (score 0):

Open iBooks
click the top menu "All Books v"
Scroll to the bottom & slide "Hide iCloud Books"

Answer (score 0):

Tap the top left corner of iBooks, hit select, then scroll down to the unwanted book and hit it and click delete.