# How do you delete a book on iBooks

Tags: ios, books

My brother downloaded some books on my iBooks account and I want it permanently off my purchased and all books thing. I have iOS 8.1.2 so none of the answers in the previous question.

Answer (score 2):

Touch on "select" button

[image]

Select the book and touch on "trash" button

[image]

Or you have a similar question to completely delete an iBook :

[Is it possible to COMPLETELY delete a Book from my purchased books?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132778/is-it-possible-to-completely-delete-an-ibooks)