# How do delete selective iCloud book copy?

Tags: icloud, ibook

I dont want few icloud book copies to be occupying my screen space. Is there anyway possible, going to the folder directly on Mac, to delete the copy of the ibooks?

I can see numerous answers of hiding and some answering that it is not possible. Are there any hacks around?

[Is it possible to COMPLETELY delete a Book from my purchased books?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132778/is-it-possible-to-completely-delete-an-ibooks)

Answer (score 1):

Right Click > Delete
"Are you sure you want to delete this book from your Mac?"
Delete.

It's in the Trash.