# Is there a way to permanently remove the iBooks app from a device?

Tags: ipad

I am trying to remove the app completely as I do not want it as it takes up a third of my memory on my iPad. Is there any way of removing it altogether please??

Comment: You cannot remove the core Apple Apps - but what makes you think it's taking up a third of your memory? On my iPhone it's 7MB. Maybe you just need to delete some of your books?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to COMPLETELY delete an iBooks?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132778/is-it-possible-to-completely-delete-an-ibooks)

Comment: @mgiordi It is not a duplicate as the other question's title was misleading - that question asks how to delete one book not the app

Comment: I have a 16gb iPad the iBooks app is 5gb therefore one third of the memory. I have deleted all books but still takes the memory space.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Apple does not allow you to remove the app completely, however if you go inside the app and delete all the books and PDF's the app should be less than 5mb.

(Which even on a 16gb phone is negligible)

To delete all books/PDFs:

1. Open iBooks
2. Make sure all books is selected in the top dropdown menu.
3. Click Select and select all books
4. Then delete

Then go to Settings -> General -> Storage and iCloud Usage -> Storage: Manage storage -> Find iBooks and it should be <5mb

If you would like to hide the app completely iOS 9.3 has a new glitch that allows you to do this, video for that is [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvuSYYExSpY).